# How do I restore a Time Machine backup after repartitioning the original drive?

Tags: macos, time-machine, partition

My goal is to backup my data by Time Machine, perform a clean install of Yosemite, partition the disk and restore some of the data.

Right now my setup is only one partition. After a new setup I want to have two partitions.

Does Time Machine deal with that smoothly though the new partitions have new UUIDs then?

Comment: Flagged "unclear what you are asking". You may create up to 16 partitions using Disk Utility. I recommend to first partition your disk, then install OS X and then migrate your data. But...maybe I just don't understand your question

Comment: Right now my setup is only one partition. After a new setup I want to have two partitions. Does time machine deal with that smoothly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. OS X handles the two new partitions and as long as the data fits on the one you restore to, no issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you restore via time machine (using Migration Assistant or Setup), then it will start backing up to the TM drive like before you restored. Not sure what you mean by if there should be a partitioned disk, as all disks have to be partitioned before you can use it.